# Cómo usar getch en raspberry OS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

estoy intentando hacer un programa que reciba un carácter sin tener que pulsar enter para posteriormente usar un lector de código de barras en un raspberry, ocurre que he probado varias librerías (getch, py-getch) y código como el que está a continuación, pero ninguno funciona, aquí mi código y error para cada caso.

Intento 1, con código que encontré en otra pregunta:

```
class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self): return self.impl()


class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch


class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()


getch = _Getch()
key = getch()
print(key)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Prueba Lector.py", line 39, in <module>
    key = getch()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Prueba Lector.py", line 10, in call
    def call(self): return self.impl()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Prueba Lector.py", line 20, in call
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Intento 2, con librerias getch y py-getch.

```
from getch import getch

key = getch()
print(key)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "main", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    MainCPythonBackend(target_cwd).mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 62, in mainloop
    msg = self._fetch_next_incoming_message(timeout=0.01)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython/cpython_backend.py", line 173, in _fetch_next_incoming_message
    self._read_one_incoming_message()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 122, in _read_one_incoming_message
    msg = parse_message(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/common.py", line 227, in parse_message
    assert msg_string[0] == MESSAGE_MARKER
AssertionError

Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart.
```

En windows probé ambas y no me dieron ningún problema.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.